# IF function with MID function

Tags: excel

```
ID                   Result region
201030102600381      Location 1
201050150200032      Location 2
201010110300031      Location 3
201040140500018      Location 4
```

I would like to search from cell "A" beginning 7 words and if match result will be as location name etc... as given a Cell "B"
I tried following formulas

```
A2<=2010101,"Location 1",IF(A2<=2010102,"Location 2",IF(A2<=2010501,"Location 3")))

(MID(A2,1,7)=A2>2010101,"Location 1",IF(A2>2010102,"Location 2",IF(A2>2010501,"Location 3")))
```

Comment: In your example data, the Result regions does not seem congruent with your formula.  Your first ID:  `201030102600381` would not seem to fit with your 1st formula definition for `Location 1`, nor do any of the others.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a limited number of comparisons to make and they do not change often, a hard-coded [LOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/lookup-function-df82ce98-edf9-46ea-8189-b0470e5e0e93) may be the best way.

```
=LOOKUP(INT(LEFT(A2, 7)), {2010101,2010102,2010501,1E+99}, {"Location 1","Location 2","Location 3","Location 4"})
```

If you have very many more choices or if they often change, then a separate cross-reference lookup table and the [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) would be the way to go.